# Find when the population is growing the fastest, under the logistic model

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, exponential-function

The population $P$ of an island $y$ years after colonization is given by the function: $\displaystyle P = \frac{250}{1 + 4e^{-0.01y}}$. After how many years was the population growing the fastest?

---

I tried taking the second derivative and setting it equal to zero. From there I solved for $y$ but kept getting $y = 0$. Which doesn't make too much sense so I was wondering how anyone would go about answering this problem.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem and where exactly are you having trouble solving it?

Comment: I've tried taking the second derivative of this function but end up getting zero

Comment: My trouble is other than trying to get the second derivative, I have no direction in how to answer and approach this question

Comment: Just to clear up anything you might have, I tried taking the second derivative and setting it equal to zero. From there I solved for y but kept getting y = 0. Which doesn't make too much sense so I was wondering how anyone would go about answering this problem

Comment: remember that the points on which the derivative of a function is $0$, are candidates to be local minima or maxima of the function.

Comment: When you take a look at the second derivative of P, you will note that it is nonnegative for every value o $y$. Therefore, $P'$ is an (possibly non-strictly) increasing function. This means that the rate of growth of population either stays the same or increases.

Comment: Okay, so should I take the first or second derivative to determine after how many years the population is growing the fastest? I apologize for sounding like a dummy, I just find this question quite tricky

Answer (score 2):

This is a Logistic Growth problem. So... $$P'(y) = kP(L - P)$$
and
$$P(y) = {L \over {1 + C{e^{ - ky}}}}$$

If we add in the specifics of your problem...

$$\eqalign{
  & P = {{250} \over {1 + 4{e^{ - 0.01y}}}}  \cr 
  & P'(y) = kP(L - P) = 0.01P(250 - P) = 2.5P(y) - .01P{(y)^2}  \cr 
  & P'' = 2.5 - .02P = 0  \cr 
  & P = 125  \cr 
  & 125 = {{250} \over {1 + 4{e^{ - 0.01y}}}}  \cr 
  & 125 + 500{e^{ - 0.01y}} = 250  \cr 
  & {e^{ - 0.01y}} = .25  \cr 
  & y = {{\ln (.25)} \over { - 0.01}} = 138.62 \cr} $$

For future reference, in these types of problems the population is always growing the fastest when $$P=L/2$$

Comment: Thank you for writing an answer however is there others way to solving this problem? I am in a Calculus 12 course and we've learn taking the derivative of log. and expon. functions as well as logarithmic differiention for example

Comment: Well what we are doing is taking the function, P , that tells you the Population. The derivative of that function,  P' , is the rate of change of the population. The question wants you to maximize the rate of change. This means you have to take the derivative of P' and find it's critical points. So you would set P''=0 and solve for P. Then once you have P you plug it back into your original function and solve for y.

Comment: Okay, that makes much more sense! When you say set P'' = 0 and solve for P, how is that possible? Find the values of y?

Comment: As in the answer you get, $$P″=2.5−.02P$$
Set $$P''=0$$ so   $$2.5-.02P=0$$
Then you get find that $$P=125$$
Plug this value of P into your original function(the one you posted) and use algebra to solve for y.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea was good but, may be, there was some mistake in the calculation of the derivatives. Using, as Jake Lebovic, $$P = {L \over {1 + C{e^{ - ky}}}}$$ you have by standard differentiation $$\frac {dP}{dy}=\frac{C k L e^{-k y}}{\left(C e^{-k y}+1\right)^2}$$ $$\frac {d^2P}{dy^2}=\frac{2 C^2 k^2 L e^{-2 k y}}{\left(1+C e^{-k y}\right)^3}-\frac{C k^2 L e^{-k
   y}}{\left(1+C e^{-k y}\right)^2}=\frac{C k^2 L e^{k y} \left(C-e^{k y}\right)}{\left(C+e^{k y}\right)^3}$$ So, the second derivative cancels if $e^{ky}=C$; putting this in the expression of $P$ shows that this will happen when $P=\frac L2$ whatever could be the values of parameters $L,C,k$.